# Multivariable Limit with exponent

Tags: calculus, limits

I need help solving this multivariable limit. I tried using $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ but that gets me nowhere, can anyone help?

${\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}(1+x^2y^2)^\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}$

Comment: I think the limit is 1.

Comment: Which method did you use, could you give me some hints or explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $x=\dfrac1s$ and $y=\dfrac1t$
$${\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}(1+x^2y^2)^\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}=\lim_{(s,t)\to(\infty,\infty)}\left(1+\frac{1}{(st)^2}\right)^{(st)^2\frac{1}{s^2+t^2}}=e^0=1$$

Comment: How do know it covers all the paths ?

Comment: This limit valid for all $x\to0$ and $y\to0$, where we substitute them with $x=\dfrac1s$ and $y=\dfrac1t$. It doesn't need to check all paths which go to $(0,0)$, but if you ask me **prove this limit is 1**, I use $\epsilon-\delta$ method to show that.